# Unable to build new document

Tags: miktex, texmaker, mac

I'm on a Mac and due to a nightmare of issues with BigSur, I've had to nuke, pave and downgrade. I am now running Mojave (10.14.6). I have MiKTeX installed and confirmed that it is up to date. I've then installed Texmaker and set the preferences as shown:

[image: Snapshot of texmaker configuration options]

I've then created a new blank document using the wizard and here is the sample file I have here:

[image: Failed to run]

I can't seem to create a new file. I'm assuming it's something to do with where I'm pointing to in the LaTex and PdfLaTeX extensions, but not sure what to do about it.

Also, I have several dozen documents I've created and compiled successfully on previous installations that also cannot find the log files. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That seems to be a recurring error with texmaker. Write the author and ask for support. (the latex and pdflatex settings looks curious, but as I have neither a mac nor texmaker I don't know if this is normal or not).

Comment: I now hate Mac with a passion. In texmaker (seconds after posting this), I found the reset settings button, which seems to have gotten things working again. Which, given that these were the defaults when I installed it is extra curious.

Comment: Your commands for pdflatex and latex are wrong as far as  I can tell, since they don't actually have a command. But most Mac users are *not* using MikTeX, and most of the advice you will find online will refer to MacTeX, which is TeXLive. In all honesty I would recommend removing the MikTeX installation and using MacTeX instead. But you can try "/usr/local/bin/pdflatex" as the command name or simply "pdflatex".

Comment: @Diesel This has nothing to do with the Mac. TeXMaker is the problem, not the Mac. If you want a good Mac editor for TeX, use TeXShop. And install TeXLive not MikTeX.

Comment: @AlanMunn, that got it working! Thanks. My issues with mac extend far far beyond this little hiccup. Removing support for Java is much higher up on my list.

Comment: Even easier on the mac, install mactex, it is hands down the easiest and fastest latex installation on any platform. Texmaker or texstudio should not have any issues with mactex. They might even assume you're using mactex as miktex is most commonly used on Windows

Comment: @AlanMunn, I'll look into both of those, post-burning-progress-report-deadline. I'm very new to Latex and am loving it. I went this way, as my whole lab recommended this setup, not that it was a good one, just that it was what they used and I got comfortable with